# Add a Mongo GeoJSON 2dsphere index on LoopbackJs' attribute GeoPoint

Tags: mongodb, indexing, loopbackjs

As the title suggests i tried to add a 2dsphere index on my GeoPoints attributes on LoopbackJs.
My MongoDB shell version is 3.2.3 - so it should do.

Here are my tries so far:

- Adding enableGeoIndexing in my server/datasource.js

  ```
        {
  ...
  "myDs": {
          "host": "localhost",
          "port": 27017,
          "database": "myDB",
          "name": "myDs",
          "connector": "mongodb",
          "enableGeoIndexing": true
        }
  ```

  ...
      }

Nothing seemed to change.

- Adding indexes the Loopback way  + having an autoupdate script:

  `{
        "name": "NsUser",
        "base": "User",
        "idInjection": true,
        "options": {
          "validateUpsert": true
        },
         "indexes": {
          "geopoint_index": {
            "geopoint": "2dsphere"
          }
        },
        "properties": {
          "created": {
            "type": "date"
          },
          "firstname": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "lastname": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "geopoint": {
            "type": "geopoint"
          },
      ...
      }
  …
  }`

And I'm getting an error :

```
"ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "Can't extract geo keys: { _id: ObjectId('5807689f01723b3ca6ba08e5'), created: new Date(1426545369000), email: \"xxx@gmail.com\", firstname: \"Louis\", lastname: \"L\", geopoint: { lat: -17.52243049, lng: -149.54396636 } }  can't project geometry into spherical CRS: { lat: -17.52243049, lng: -149.54396636 }",
    "code" : 16755
```

Answer (score 4):

The only solution I found to add the 2dsphere index is to add a new attribute `geopoint_mongo` which is an array `[lng, lat]` .

Here's the script I used to convert the datas:

```
NsUser.createMongoGeoloc = function (cb) {
        NsUser.find(function (err, users) {
            var count = 0;
            users.forEach(function (user) {
                var change = false;
                if (user.geopoint && user.geopoint.lat && user.geopoint.lng) {
                    count++;
                    user.geopoint_mongo = [user.geopoint.lng, user.geopoint.lat];
                    change = true;
                }
                if (change) {
                    NsUser.upsert(user);
                }
            });
            cb(err, count);
        });
    };

    NsUser.remoteMethod(
            'createMongoGeoloc',
            {
                description: 'Update the Geolocation for NsUser',
                returns: {arg: 'count', type: 'number'},
                http: {verb: 'put'}
            }
    );
```

Then adding the mongo index did the trick:

```
db.NsUser.createIndex({geopoint_mongo:"2dsphere"})
```

But as you can see it does not really answer the question - it is just a workaround.